# Where to daven in Logan airport (Boston)?

Tags: tefilla, travel

Is there a convenient place to daven in Boston's Logan airport around 7:30 am?

Comment: “not enough time to leave the airport”? In that case, consider finding an empty gate (that won’t begin boarding while you’re praying) and pray there. If you’ll feel uncomfortable [and find it hard to focus] just say the time-restricted pieces and then *daven like a mentsch* with the *davening* paraphernalia when you can go somewhere outside the airport.

Comment: Did you mean with a minyan? Or are you asking to pray by yourself? For the latter, I normally go to an empty gate, in a quiet corner.

Comment: You won't find a minyon at the airport, here in Boston. Dude's answer is fairly on point and it's what I've done when I've needed to take an early flight and couldn't make it to schul first

Comment: Some airports have a *meditation room* with no religious items in it. Ask if they have one there or something called a *chapel* which has no *religious* paraphernalia.

Comment: Good idea, but the Boston airport has only a Catholic chapel, quite large with associated religious accoutrements, or so the airport website indicates.

Answer (score 4):

The waiting area by the gate your plane will be arriving at or in your seat on the plane itself are just fine for davening

Comment: This is what I've done when I haven't had time to go to schul before leaving home on a flight.